# Unable to implement search box

Tags: android, search, searchview

I am new here and hope you can help me out. I have a an app, which uses remote.xml for data. Now I want to implement a search dialog to search and return results. However I face some issue. I have followed the 2 guides http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html and http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html (I am not sure which one is more applicable as it seems it has conflicting info). All I want is to implement a search box (and not the widget).

I have managed to implement the Search Dialog and it opens when clicked. However, after added the following code, it crashed when the app was launched (it debug at the setSearchableInfo and logcat doesnt show any siginicant info. I am lost.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
           (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    **searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));**

    return true;
}
```

My Manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >     

        <activity android:name="com.fab.mov.MIListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
             <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                 </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value="com.fab.mov.MIListActivity" />
         </activity>
```

My searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

My main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/app_label"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
```

And I added the following activity in the list activity

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.feed_list);

        //setContentView(R.layout.action_search);

        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        //  doMySearch(query);
        }

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
               // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
       (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
      SearchView searchView =
          (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
     searchView.setSearchableInfo(
           searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Appreciate someone the help me on this. Thank you.

LogCat error log as follows:

05-04 00:28:54.675: E/ActivityThread(3813): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at com.fappbulously.movie.MIListActivity.setUpSearchView(MIListActivity.java:267)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at com.fappbulously.movie.MIListActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MIListActivity.java:249)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2445)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:401)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:767)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2922)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4447)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-04 00:28:55.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3813):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you forgot to set the `SearchView` as `actionViewClass` on your `action_search` menu item in `main.xml`, so it's null:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

Comment: Great! Thanks very much, BladeCoder! Finally no error! But the search functions doesnt work. When I try to search, it didn't do anything. Is there anything I miss out?

Comment: You only need to set the android.app.default_searchable meta data on the activities that do not perform the actual search but should provide the search interface.
Now your code is working but you need to implement the actual search. Your search activity will receive the first search data in onCreate() and the following search data in onNewIntent() each time you validate the search query. onNewIntent() is called because your search activity is in singleTop mode, so it's not recreated each time.

Comment: Thanks. I have remove it out but it still doesnt work. Do I have to setup class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity in order to work? I haven't done anything on that yet.

Comment: Just read the guide you mentioned in your question and once you have retrieved the search data, perform the actual search and display the results.

Comment: Okie. Thanks for your help once again. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me (because you have not posted the logcat, please do it) there must be some compatibility issue.The links have not specified any thing from support library and there could lie the issue. I think your app is supporting less than 3.0. And Dont be confused used the seach-dialog interface
 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the logcat error as above. IT doesnt seems to point to anything...appreciate your help.

Comment: seems like a list activity error, ?? need the code for entire class

Comment: I dont think so as I have define as follows. Anything I can do to check? Sorry I am newbie developer <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: I updated as above. The crashed only happen after I added searchView.setSearchableInfo (and aboved lines). Before that, I can activate and trigger the dialog, just that nothing happen when I type to search. Do I need to create a new layout to display the search result? I havent done tat.

Comment: actually it was dumb of me to ask you the support version,  if there was such an error it would have appeared during compilation , best of luck and happy coding